# How can I get greasemonkey to call a function on a page after it loads

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I have a very simple greasemonkey script that I want to call an already existing javascript function on the page. I've read the documentation and nothing seems to work

```
window.setTimeout(function() { 
    alert('test') // This alert works, but nothing after it does
    myFunction() // undefined
    window.myFunction() // undefined
    document.myFunction() // undefined
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try using:
unsafeWindow.myFunction();

More details and info - http://wiki.greasespot.net/UnsafeWindow

Comment: Thanks, I'm marking your answer as the accepted answer because the link provides some alternatives. I found that attaching the script to the page is really the best solution for what I need.

Comment: I would suggest using `locaction.href = 'javascript:...'` instead of unsafeWindow if you want your script to be more compatible (ive had some problems with unsafeWindow TamperMonkey for Chrome)

Comment: `unsafeWindow not defined`

Answer (score 19):

One way to call a function in the original page is like this:

```
location.href = "javascript:void(myFunction());";
```

It is a bit ugly. There is also the [unsafeWindow](http://wiki.greasespot.net/UnsafeWindow) provided by GreaseMonkey too, but the authors advise against using it.

```
unsafeWindow.myFunction();
```

Looks neater but make sure you understand the ramifications. From the manual:

> unsafeWindow bypasses Greasemonkey's
>   XPCNativeWrapper-based security model,
>   which exists to make sure that
>   malicious web pages cannot alter
>   objects in such a way as to make
>   greasemonkey scripts (which execute
>   with more privileges than ordinary
>   Javascript running in a web page) do
>   things that their authors or users did
>   not intend. User scripts should
>   therefore avoid calling or in any
>   other way depending on any properties
>   on unsafeWindow - especally if if they
>   are executed for arbitrary web pages,
>   such as those with @include *, where
>   the page authors may have subverted
>   the environment in this way.

In other words, your script elevates the privileges available to the original page script if you use unsafeWindow.

Comment: location.href = "javascript:..." is the better way in most cases

Answer (score 7):

You could try using javascript event listeners.

These execute code on response to object events occurring (such as page load)

For example, to execute code on page load:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () 
{
    /* code goes here */
});
```

Comment: addEventListener is missing a closing ')' parenthesis after the '}'.

Comment: I have just fixed the syntax, thank you.